# How to run googletest in CLion?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, googletest

I want to use Googletest in my CLion Project.
So here is what I did:
I copied my googletest folder into the lib folder of my project.
I changed my CMakeLists.txt files like described in that Video: https://youtu.be/8Up5eNZ0FLw
and created that simple test:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
TEST(basic_check, test_eq){
    EXPECT_EQ(1,0);
}
```

I tried to run the test by pressing Shift + Ctrl + F10 and I got the following error:

```
"F:\Programs\CLion 2016.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Christian\ClionProjects\Geldautomat\cmake-build-debug --target runBasicTests -- -j 4
[ 16%] Building CXX object Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
In file included from C:/Users/Christian/ClionProjects/Geldautomat/Tests/lib/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40:0,
                 from C:/Users/Christian/ClionProjects/Geldautomat/Tests/lib/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:58,
                 from C:\Users\Christian\ClionProjects\Geldautomat\Tests\lib\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc:39:
C:/Users/Christian/ClionProjects/Geldautomat/Tests/lib/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h: In function 'int testing::internal::posix::StrCaseCmp(const char*, const char*)':
C:/Users/Christian/ClionProjects/Geldautomat/Tests/lib/googletest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:2328:25: error: '_stricmp' was not declared in this scope
return _stricmp(s1, s2);
                     ^
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [runBasicTests] Error 2
Tests\lib\googletest\CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:162: recipe for target 'Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:267: recipe for target 'Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:200: recipe for target 'runBasicTests' failed
```

My CMakeLists.txt in this directory is:

```
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(runBasicTests
        basic_check.cpp)

target_link_libraries(runBasicTests gtest gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(runBasicTests src)
```

Where my Source Code can be found in directory src.
My main.cpp is in the root directory and my Basic Test is in Tests/basic_tests

Tried the same on my Linux Notebook with CLion. Got the Error:

```
/home/christian/Downloads/clion-2016.3/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/christian/ClionProjects/Geldautomat/cmake-build-debug --target runBasicTests -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[ 16%] Building CXX object Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libgtest.a
[ 33%] Built target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target gtest_main
[ 50%] Building CXX object Tests/lib/googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX static library libgtest_main.a
[ 66%] Built target gtest_main
Scanning dependencies of target runBasicTests
[ 83%] Building CXX object Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/basic_check.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable runBasicTests
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lsrc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'Tests/basic_tests/runBasicTests' failed
gmake[3]: *** [Tests/basic_tests/runBasicTests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:256: recipe for target 'Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/all' failed
gmake[2]: *** [Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:268: recipe for target 'Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/rule' failed
gmake[1]: *** [Tests/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicTests.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:201: recipe for target 'runBasicTests' failed
gmake: *** [runBasicTests] Error 2
```

It would be fine if my Project runs on Linux..

Any suggestions?

-ChrizZ

Comment: `src` is not a library so get rid of this line: `target_link_libraries(runBasicTests src)`

Comment: ok. It worked on Linux. So I can work on it somehow. On Windows I still get the first part of my error..

Comment: Some one with google test experience will have to answer that. I know CMake but not google test.

Comment: But thanks. You helped me a lot. I dont have any experience with CMake and just tried to copy from that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link ->

`https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvHU1FkIE-ogFTtXnKZsqWA`

There are 2 videos. Both are helpful. I set up `googleTest` in my `CLion` yesterday following the `8:19` long video.